# Beamer keeps asking PIN code connecting to Apple TV

Tags: ios, appletv, airplay

All of a sudden Beamer can't connect to my Apple TV anymore. When I'd like to play a movie it asks PIN code. I enter the PIN code displayed on the TV screen, and seemingly it does not accept it because in the following moment a new enter password window comes up in [Beamer](https://beamer-app.com) and a bit later a new PIN code is displayed on the TV.

Something went south. I haven't changed my network setup and haven't touched any setup of Apple TV.

However, my Iphone can connect to Apple TV and I can use it as remote. I can connect to Apple TV from my Macbook Pro and share my screen. Beamer is displayed in Apple TV setups as `Unknown device`.

I checked, 25 March a new TvOs was released, my device has this version. Is there any chance Apple introduced something "magic" in this update cause my issue? If it is true, in general how quickly Beamer guys release some solution for this?

I did so far the following any result:

- restart MBP
- restart Apple TV
- delete Beamer with its cache and other crap it produces (ForkLift helps to delete these files as far as I see)
- Beamer beta version (no available beta version right now)
- factory reset of Apple TV
- I read through multiple issues on Apple's site, but no result

Honeslty, I run out of possible solutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the beamer is asking for the code then has the beamer updated itself lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. Definitely an issue with the new tvOS. Beamer just has to update their app so it's compatible. I've already shot an email to their support team to let them know. Right now the only workaround I've found is to set the Apple TV to require a password (not a 4 digit PIN) - it should say what it is directly below that (like a 6 digit number) and then when Beamer asks for the password - just enter that and it'll accept it.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I also messaged their support team. I will try the workaround.

Comment: I set  Apple TV so it asks password always and I can confirm that it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

i've been dealing with this for the past few days too, really annoying. i'd reluctantly accept the need to keep apple tv's password requirement on, but beamer refuses to remember that password even when the box is checked in the beamer prompt, so it's bugging me for that same 6-digit password before each and every file i try to play, i can't even relax for the length of a playlist. updated beamer to 3.3.4 today but it didn't do a thing to help with this new password problem. have written beamer support a couple of times too but they've never been responsive so i'm not surprised i haven't heard back.

Comment: I updated Beamer too, and it works fine without password.

Comment: yeah i don't know, my beamer is still acting up, kinda driving me crazy as i've been using it more than usual. my apple tv 4k is running tvOS 12.2 (16L226). regardless of my airplay settings (open to everyone, open to network, open to nearby, no password required, etc.) beamer keeps insisting a password is needed for every file, and then forgets that password after each file (since requiring a pw is now necessary to play any file & settings have no effect), so the prompts are constant. you're lucky if everything is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to my new Apple 4K with the updated remote. Every "session" it would require a 4 digit pin code, regardless of selecting "Remember Password".

After reading this article, I attempted to change the settings of the Apple TV to require password. This is what I did.

1. Set Airplay to require a password, and set that password to a 4 digit pin.
2. Quit & Restart Beamer 3.5 and load a file, it will ask for the password, enter the new 4 digit pin, and click remember password.
3. On the Apple TV 4K tvOS 14.6, change Airplay to "Allow Access: Same Network & Nearby".
4. Quite & Restart Beamer, test load a file, it should load without requiring a password. Tested with multiple files, the queue now works.

Note; this may have been something to do with preferences being reset, or something being triggered and set on the Apple TV, but either way, I am a happy camper again.